# How can I store an array in a MD array, and return that array from function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character

I have a method that takes in a list of files, and gets data about the files.  The format of those files is returned as two 1D arrays.  I want to combine those into a single 2D array.

The files only return with a type array, and a data array.

Here is the method in question.  I'm successfully getting the data I need out of the files and into the 1D array, but when I try to add them to the 2D array, it runs (but gives a warning that char * and char *[][] aren't equivalent).

```
char *ParseFiles(char *listOfFiles[32])
{
    char *allFileData;
    char *tmpArray[32][32];

    allFileData = tmpArray;

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles[i]; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        // Get the File Type
        char *currentFileType = GetFileType(listOfFiles[i], strlen(listOfFiles[i]));

        if(currentFileType)
        {
            // Warning char * and char *[][] are not equivalent.
            tmpArray[i][j] = currentFileType;
            printf("File %d is %s\n", i, currentFileType);
            //printf("File %d is %s\n", i, &tmpArray[i][j]);
            //free(currentFileType);
        }

        //Get all File Data
        // Warning char * and char *[][] are not equivalent.
        char *currentFileData = GetFileData(listOfFiles[i]);

        j = j + 1;
        if(currentFileData)
        {
            tmpArray[i][j] = currentFileData;
            printf("File Data:\n%s\n", currentFileData);
            //free(currentFileType);
        }
    }
    return allFileData;
}
```

When I try to output the `tmpArray[][]` values in the printf statements that are commented out, I get unexpected characters (unexpected to someone who is making a mistake) `?]p`

Is the problem based on the warning of the two char arrays not being the same type, or is it because I'm trying to insert the single dimensional array into a multi dimensional array incorrectly?

The exact warning I am getting is `warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'char*' from 'char *[32][32]'`

---

Below are my other two methods, and my main:

```
char *GetFileType(char *filePath, int size)
{
    char *ret = malloc(size);

    char currentLine[100];
    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");

    while(fgets(currentLine, sizeof(currentLine), file) != NULL)
    {
        if(strstr(currentLine, "test"))
        {
            ret = "test";
        }

        else if(strstr(currentLine, "production"))
        {
            ret = "production";
        }
    }
    if(!ret)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return ret;

}

char *GetFileData(char *filePath)
{

    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");

    // Get the buffer size
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);

    // Reset the position of the stream
    rewind(file);

    buffer = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));

    // Read the entire file into the buffer
    fread(buffer, size, 1, file);

    buffer[size] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}

int main (void)
{
    char *listOfFiles[32] = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"};

    ParseFiles(listOfFiles);

    printf("Press ENTER key to Continue");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(listOfFiles[i])` will give you the size of the *pointer* not the length of the string it points to, you want [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) for that.

Comment: Also note that you have a *memory leak* in your `GetFileType` function. If you want to copy a string you need to use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). Also don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* needs space allocated for it as well.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I fixed the ```sizeof```, and I'm looking into what you mean on ```GetFileType```.  I'll handle the null-terminated byte string the way I handled it in GetFileData by adding the null-terminator.  I'm not sure I see what you mean about needing ```strcpy``` though.

Comment: First you do `char *ret = malloc(size);`. That makes `ret` point to the memory you allocate. Then you do e.g. `ret = "test";`. That makes `ret` point somewhere else, you lose the original pointer to the memory you allocated. And since the memory that `ret` is pointing to wasn't allocated by `malloc`, you can no longer pass the pointer to `free`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't where you say it is, it is here instead:

```
char *allFileData;
char *tmpArray[32][32];

allFileData = tmpArray;
```

The type of `tmpArray` is `char *[32][32]`. The type of `allFileData` is `char *`. The assignment is simply not valid.

And there's one even worse thing happening: You returning `allFileData` which is pointing to the *local variable* `tmpArray`. The variable `tmpArray` will go out of scope once the function returns, and the pointer you return will become invalid immediately. Either pass the array in as an argument, or allocate it dynamically inside the function.